# Radio button display issue in pdf generate

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

radio button issue in pdf generate when i'm using wkhtmltopdf  to generate pdf :

below my Html code with radio button :

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
```

below my pdf generation code :

```
var report = new ActionAsPdf("GenerateDetailPdf")
{
    FileName = "LoanDetail_" + loanId + ".pdf",
    CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type --disable-smart-shrinking   --footer-center \"Page: [page] of [toPage]\"",
    PageHeight = 300,
    PageWidth = 300,
    PageMargins = new Margins(10, 0, 10, 0)
};
```

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: just display name of inputs not with buttons.